# Redux dispatch action taking too long despite reducer function attached executes fast

Tags: performance, redux, react-redux, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting chrome violation errors of type `setTimeout handler took 500+ ms` which are seriously blocking my app, and some happen every time an action attached to a websocket payload comes and is processed. I tried debugging it with the chrome profiler, and this is what it shows exactly at the point when payload is processed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdP7X.jpg

The `(anonymous)` function is the one in the reducer and the time ran coincides with the error.

Here is some code.

```js
// ACTION
const someAction = (data): Thunk => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const t = performance.now();
    dispatch(someAction(data));
    console.log('after dispatching cellReceived', performance.now() - t); 
    // logs 800+ ms and is consistent with chrome violation errors (setTimeout handler took <N> ms
  }
}

// REDUCER
  export default(state: State, action: Actions) {
  switch(action.type) {
    ...
    case ActionType.someAction: {
      const { data } = action.payload;
      const t = performance.now();
      (... do calculations here)
      console.log(performance.now() - t) // logs 30ms
    }
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help, I must have spent over 20 hours this week reading about this issue and trying to debug it. I didn't find any good resources on how to properly debug with chrome's profiler.

Comment: Enable [V8 stats and all events](https://puu.sh/Ip7Bx/87d8dd6469.png) in devtools settings: maybe it's some internal function like JSON.stringify, etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm I still don't see anything relevant, though I must say again, I am not really an expert with the profiler tool.

Comment: @wOxxOm https://imgur.com/a/ZnS0ZlG I updated the imgur with more info, `onMessageListener` is the function attached to `message` handler in the component that sets up web sockets functionality with `mqtt.js`

Comment: It's impossible to guess without seeing the full call stack so like I already supposed it might be serializing the data in order to send them.

Comment: @wOxxOm I used this article to see if I get more info on the functions that are actually running. https://v8.dev/docs/rcs 

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, this is what I see when I follow the steps: https://imgur.com/a/MiGH7cL

Whereas in the docs you can actually see the functions that are running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually need to be the dispatch or reducer. Under certain circumstances, React will start a rerender synchronously, as a direct result of the `dispatch` - so before your `console.log('after dispatching cellReceived', performance.now() - t);`  line

So this could also be a very slow React render.

If you want to make sure:

```js
import { batch } from 'react-redux'

const someAction = (data): Thunk => async dispatch => {
  try {
    batch(() => {
        const t = performance.now();
        dispatch(someAction(data));
        console.log('after dispatching cellReceived', performance.now() - t); 
    })
  } catch {/*...*/}
}
```

Comment: I actually think it was a very slow re-render, I was using nivo - a react charts library - to render about 30 charts with realtime data and it turns out it's not the best library for this use case after all, I did not know why would it show this kind of error, but now it makes sense, the rendering of svgs probably uses some of the methods that cause forced layout/reflow. Anyway I found that batching more updates together is easier on the interface, so now I just batch 10 updates together instead of updating 10 times for each - temporary solution but it works better.